# Longest contiguous Increasing Subset in java

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have tried to come up with a solution to the longest increasing subsequence problem.Can this solution be optimized further?

Example 1:

- Input: {5,4,3,7,8,9,11}
- Output: 3, 7, 8, 9, 11

Example 2:

- Input: {1,2,1,2,1}
- Output: 1, 2 (the latest one)

Implementation:

```
 public class LongestIncreasingSubsequence {

        public static ArrayList<Integer>[] getLongestIncreasingSubsequence(int[] array, ArrayList<Integer>[] list,
                int index) {

            list[index] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            if (index == 0) {
                list[index].add(array[index]);

            }

            else {

                if (array[index] > array[index - 1]) {
                    list[index].addAll(list[index - 1]);

                }

                    list[index].add(array[index]);

               }

            if (index == array.length - 1)
                return list;

            return getLongestIncreasingSubsequence(array, list, index + 1);

        }

        public static List<Integer> findLIS(int[] array) {

            ArrayList<Integer>[] arrayList = getLongestIncreasingSubsequence(array, new ArrayList[array.length], 0);

            int maxLength = arrayList[array.length - 1].size();
            int maxIndex = array.length - 1;
            for (int i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (arrayList[i].size() > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = arrayList[i].size();
                    maxIndex = i;
                }

            }

            return arrayList[maxIndex];

        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            int[] array = new int[] { 7, 1, 3, 8, 11 };

            List<Integer> LIS = findLIS(array);

            for (Integer i : LIS)
                System.out.print(i + ",");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an input array of `N` values, the current implementation creates `N` instances of `ArrayList`. But you only need 2:

- One to store the longest sequence seen so far
- One to store the currently tracking sequence

For example the input 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, walking through the elements from the start:

- 5: the first element -> add it to the current sequence
- 6: greater than the previous -> add it to the current sequence
- 7: greater than the previous -> add it to the current sequence
- 1: the current sequence is broken -> the current sequence is longer than the longest sequence -> update the longest sequence = [5, 6, 7]
- 2: greater than the previous -> add it to the current sequence
- 3: greater than the previous -> add it to the current sequence
- 4: greater than the previous -> add it to the current sequence
- Reached the end -> the current sequence is longer than the longest sequence -> the longest sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4]

The implementation can be simplified to:

```
public static List<Integer> findLIS(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> longest = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<>();

    int previous = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int value : array) {
        if (value <= previous) {
            if (longest.size() < current.size()) {
                longest = current;
            }
            current = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        current.add(value);
        previous = value;
    }

    return longest.size() < current.size() ? current : longest;
}
```

Some other tips on the original code:

- Avoid arrays of generic types such as `ArrayList<Integer>[]`
- Prefer interface types in declarations and method return types, such as `List` instead of `ArrayList`
- When initializing generic types, Java 7 can guess the correct type parameter, so instead of `new ArrayList<Integer>()` you can write `new ArrayList<>()` (also known as the diamond operator `<>`)
- The indentation and formatting was inconsistent, use an IDE to format the code nicely
- Instead of printing elements of `LIS` one by one, `System.out.println(LIS)` would easily produce an output that's just as readable
- A more compact writing style to initialize an array: `int[] array = { 7, 1, 3, 8, 11 };`

Comment: Thank you very much!  never thought i need only two lists :)